# How to parse XML using Unmarshal

Tags: xml, parsing, go

I coded a very simple XML parser in Go, but my xml.Unmarshal function doesn't work properly. This is sample code.

I'm not sure if my struct is correct or not. I read some pages and I think this format is more organized.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "encoding/xml"
)

//this a xml sample of my document. 

var str = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
    <mensagem>
        <cabecalho>
            <identificacaoTransacao>
                <tipoTransacao>DESCRICAO</tipoTransacao>
                <sequencialTransacao>5443811</sequencialTransacao>
                <dataRegistroTransacao>2020-02-27</dataRegistroTransacao>
                <horaRegistroTransacao>17:35:11</horaRegistroTransacao>
            </identificacaoTransacao>
            <origem>
                <registroANS>005711</registroANS>
            </origem>
            <destino>
                <identificacaoPrestador>
                    <codigoPrestadorNaOperadora>687146</codigoPrestadorNaOperadora>
                </identificacaoPrestador>
    </destino>
    <Padrao>3.03.03</Padrao>
    </cabecalho>
</mensagem>`

    type XmlTISSIndex struct {
            XMLCabecalho struct {
                XMLAnsIdentificacaoTransacao struct {
                    XMLAnstipoTransacao         string `xml:"tipoTransacao"`
                    XMLAnsSequenciaTransacao    string `xml:"sequencialTransacao"`
                    XMLAnsDataRegistroTransacao string `xml:"dataRegistroTransacao"`
                    XMLAnsHoraRegistroTransacao string `xml:"horaRegistroTransacao"`
                }
                XMLAnsOrigem struct {
                    XMLAnsRegistro string `xml:"registroANS"`
                }
                XMLAnsDestino struct {
                    XMLAnsIdentificacaoPrestador struct {
                        XMLAnsCodigoPrestadorNaOperadora string `xml:"codigoPrestadorNaOperadora"`
                }
          }
       }
    }

func main() {

    // variables

        var data XmlTISSIndex   

        buffer := make([]byte,len(str))
        buffer = []byte(str)
        xml.Unmarshal(buffer,&data)
        fmt.Print(data)
        fmt.Println(data.XMLCabecalho.XMLAnsIdentificacaoTransacao.XMLAnsDataRegistroTransacao)
        fmt.Println(data.XMLCabecalho.XMLAnsIdentificacaoTransacao.XMLAnsHoraRegistroTransacao)
        fmt.Println(data.XMLCabecalho.XMLAnsIdentificacaoTransacao.XMLAnsSequenciaTransacao)
        fmt.Println(data.XMLCabecalho.XMLAnsIdentificacaoTransacao.XMLAnstipoTransacao)
}
```

Comment: When I run this code, information about data is not printed.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you were building your structs was incorrect.  Also, because you are using ISO-8859-1 encoding, that made things a little more tricky..

I used [this article](https://medium.com/@github.gkarthiks/decoding-iso-8859-1-in-go-68979f7d65c6) for assistance in figuring this out.

Something like this should work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/html/charset" // <-- Had to use this due to ISO-8859-1 encoding
)

// Sample document
var str = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
    <mensagem>
        <cabecalho>
            <identificacaoTransacao>
                <tipoTransacao>DESCRICAO</tipoTransacao>
                <sequencialTransacao>5443811</sequencialTransacao>
                <dataRegistroTransacao>2020-02-27</dataRegistroTransacao>
                <horaRegistroTransacao>17:35:11</horaRegistroTransacao>
            </identificacaoTransacao>
            <origem>
                <registroANS>005711</registroANS>
            </origem>
            <destino>
                <identificacaoPrestador>
                    <codigoPrestadorNaOperadora>687146</codigoPrestadorNaOperadora>
                </identificacaoPrestador>
            </destino>
            <Padrao>3.03.03</Padrao>
        </cabecalho>
    </mensagem>`

type IdentificacaoTransacao struct {
    XMLName               xml.Name `xml:"identificacaoTransacao"`
    TipoTransacao         string   `xml:"tipoTransacao"`
    SequencialTransacao   string   `xml:"sequencialTransacao"`
    DataRegistroTransacao string   `xml:"dataRegistroTransacao"`
    HoraRegistroTransacao string   `xml:"horaRegistroTransacao"`
}

type Origem struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"origem"`
    RegistroANS string   `xml:"registroANS"`
}

type IdentificacaoPrestador struct {
    XMLName                    xml.Name `xml:"identificacaoPrestador"`
    CodigoPrestadorNaOperadora string   `xml:"codigoPrestadorNaOperadora"`
}

type Destino struct {
    XMLName                xml.Name               `xml:"destino"`
    IdentificacaoPrestador IdentificacaoPrestador `xml:"identificacaoPrestador"`
}

type Cabecalho struct {
    XMLName                xml.Name               `xml:"cabecalho"`
    IdentificacaoTransacao IdentificacaoTransacao `xml:"identificacaoTransacao"`
    Origem                 Origem                 `xml:"origem"`
    Destino                Destino                `xml:"destino"`
    Padrao                 string                 `xml:"Padrao"`
}

type Mensagem struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name  `xml:"mensagem"`
    Cabecalho Cabecalho `xml:"cabecalho"`
}

func main() {
    var mensagem Mensagem
    var err error

    byteStr := []byte(str)

    reader := bytes.NewReader(byteStr)
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(reader)
    decoder.CharsetReader = charset.NewReaderLabel
    err = decoder.Decode(&mensagem)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Decoder error:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(mensagem)
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
{{ mensagem} {{ cabecalho} {{ identificacaoTransacao} DESCRICAO 5443811 2020-02-27 17:35:11} {{ origem} 005711} {{ destino} {{ identificacaoPrestador} 687146}} 3.03.03}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Matt. I read the article that you send me and I change a little bit your code. I create a consolidate struct, because I thing is easy to understand. The code works fine!!!